# InDesign scripting of the Socket object yields cryptic error message

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I'm working on a broadcast e-mail template that would pull the latest three articles off our blog from an RSS feed and insert the relevant sections into the document.

I looked at the [documentation](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/scripting/pdfs/javascript_tools_guide.pdf), and based on the bit about the `File` object, some of my own debugging, and an [InDesign forum post](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4026092) I've learned that it's not possible to use the `File` object to source an online XML file.

The alternative (without resorting to an external script, one of which didn't work for me anyways), it seems, is to use the `Socket` object. So I went back to the documentation and copied/pasted this code verbatim from there:

```
reply = "";
conn = new Socket;
// access Adobe’s home page
if (conn.open ("www.adobe.com:80")) {
// send a HTTP GET request
conn.write ("GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\n\n");
// and read the server’s reply
reply = conn.read(999999);
conn.close();
}
```

When I ran it, I received this descriptive error message:

[image: Thanks for this error message, Adobe!]

A search for "89858 javascript error" yielded nothing useful.

So I'm stuck. Either Adobe's code sample has an error, or, more likely, there's something wrong on my end. If I had to guess, I'd guess that it's some kind of proxy problem, but I don't know for sure and don't know how to find out.

Can anyone help? The principles of the `Socket` object make sense to me, but if I can't get even the sample to work, I don't really have anywhere to go with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error above occurs when you return certain objects (XML, Socket) from a function call, but the return values does not get assigned anywhere.

```
function test() {
    var xml = new XML('<test />');
    return xml;
}
test();
```

The above will cause an error. To get around it you have to assign the return value somewhere.

```
var result = test();
```

---

Try to put all collect all function calls result. I am not sure which one causes the error.

```
var reply = "";
var conn = new Socket;
// access Adobe’s home page
if (conn.open ("www.adobe.com:80")) {
    // send a HTTP GET request
    var result = conn.write ("GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\n\n");
    // and read the server’s reply
    reply = conn.read(999999);
    var close = conn.close();
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to tie your response into my scenario, and I'm having trouble. If I do `alert(reply)` it no longer throws an error, but the alert is empty. Same if I add `toString()`. I don't think I can add a `return` value anywhere or set a variable to a function because Adobe's sample isn't contained in a function. If I'm understanding your point correctly, isn't `reply` doing the same thing as `result` is doing in your example? But it still doesn't work. Thanks for your help I really appreciate it!

Comment: I played with it for awhile, and adding an `else` statement and doing `alert(conn.error);` was the most useful way to work everything out; it gave me a descriptive error message. I'd have posted this as a separate answer but it falls in line well with your explanation, so I'm just commenting about it here! Thanks for your help!